# mysqli error: [1093: ...]

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL select, that gives two rows back.
The SQL update gives the error message 1093 back;

> mysqli error: [1093: Table 'HD_TICKET' is specified twice, both as a
>   target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data]

```
update HD_TICKET, HD_STATUS as T5
    set HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID = T5.ID, 
HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED  = IF(T5.STATE = 'opened', NOW(), HD_TICKET.TIME_OPENED), 
HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED  = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NOW(), HD_TICKET.TIME_CLOSED), 
HD_TICKET.TIME_STALLED = IF(T5.STATE = 'stalled', NOW(), HD_TICKET.TIME_STALLED), 
HD_TICKET.SATISFACTION_RATING = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NULL, HD_TICKET.SATISFACTION_RATING), 
HD_TICKET.SATISFACTION_COMMENT = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NULL, HD_TICKET.SATISFACTION_COMMENT), 
HD_TICKET.TITLE = (SELECT NAME FROM ORG1.ASSET WHERE ORG1.ASSET.ID = (SELECT ASSET_ID FROM HD_TICKET WHERE HD_TICKET.ID = HD_TICKET.PARENT_ID))
  where T5.NAME = 'New' and 
HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = T5.HD_QUEUE_ID and
    (HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>))
```

Can anybody help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 `HD_TICKET` in the statement. In the `WHERE HD_TICKET.ID = HD_TICKET.PARENT_ID`, which one of them is meant to be referenced?

Comment: Yes but the table appears twice. Once in the UPDATE and second in the internal subquery. Is the `WHERE HD_TICKET.ID` meant to reference the internal one?

Comment: Every ticket as an ID in the table HD_TICKET, some tickets are parent tickets and some tickets are child tickets. In this case - its a child ticket, i want to fill the title from this child ticket with the name of the ASSET_ID, wich is only in the parent ticket. Sorry for my english, hope you understand what I mean. Thank you!

Comment: So the `NAME` should come from the ASSET of the parent ticket of a TICKET. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand from the comments, you wanted a correlated subquery, to find the "parent" ticket and from that the realted asset (and its name):

```
HD_TICKET.TITLE = (SELECT NAME 
                   FROM ORG1.ASSET 
                   WHERE ORG1.ASSET.ID = (SELECT parent.ASSET_ID 
                                          FROM HD_TICKET AS parent
                                          WHERE parent.ID = HD_TICKET.PARENT_ID))
```

Now, you'd still get a similar error with the above code change, for the same reasons. MySQL does not allow the table that is updated to appear in a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Solution is to move the second reference to the table to the `UPDATE` clause and trasnform the subqueries into outer joins:

```
  left join HD_TICKET as PARENT 
    on PARENT.ID = T.PARENT_ID 
  left join ORG1.ASSET as A
    on A.ID = PARENT.ASSET_ID
```

Since we did that, it feels right to convert the existing join to `T5` to the same `JOIN` syntax as well:

```
update HD_TICKET as T
  join HD_STATUS as T5
    on T.HD_QUEUE_ID = T5.HD_QUEUE_ID
  left join HD_TICKET as PARENT 
    on PARENT.ID = T.PARENT_ID 
  left join ORG1.ASSET as A
    on A.ID = PARENT.ASSET_ID 
set 
  T.HD_STATUS_ID = T5.ID, 
  T.TIME_OPENED  = IF(T5.STATE = 'opened', NOW(), T.TIME_OPENED), 
  T.TIME_CLOSED  = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NOW(), T.TIME_CLOSED), 
  T.TIME_STALLED = IF(T5.STATE = 'stalled', NOW(), T.TIME_STALLED), 
  T.SATISFACTION_RATING = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NULL, T.SATISFACTION_RATING), 
  T.SATISFACTION_COMMENT = IF(T5.STATE = 'closed', NULL, T.SATISFACTION_COMMENT), 
  T.TITLE = A.NAME 
where T5.NAME = 'New'  
  and T.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>) ;
```