# mysqli error: [1093: …]

Tags: mysql

Sorry I have an similar question asked before.
But I'm a newbie with mysql and I don`t get it.. I don't know how it works.. hope someone can help me again. Thank you!

I have an SQL select, that gives one row back. The SQL update gives the error message 1093 back;

> mysqli error: [1093: Table 'ASSET_ASSOCIATION' is specified twice,
>   both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data]

```
UPDATE ORG1.ASSET_ASSOCIATION
SET ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID = 
(
SELECT ASSET_ID FROM ORG1.HD_TICKET
WHERE ID = (<TICKET_IDS>)
)
WHERE ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID = 
(
SELECT ASSOCIATED_ASSET_ID FROM ORG1.ASSET_ASSOCIATION
WHERE ASSET_FIELD_ID = 11
AND ASSET_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ORG1.ASSET WHERE ASSET.NAME = (SELECT CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 FROM ORG1.HD_TICKET WHERE ID = (<TICKET_IDS>)))
OR ASSET_FIELD_ID = 111
AND ASSET_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ORG1.ASSET WHERE ASSET.NAME = (SELECT CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 FROM ORG1.HD_TICKET WHERE ID = (<TICKET_IDS>)))
OR ASSET_FIELD_ID = 1111
AND ASSET_ID = (SELECT ID FROM ORG1.ASSET WHERE ASSET.NAME = (SELECT CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 FROM ORG1.HD_TICKET WHERE ID = (<TICKET_IDS>)))
)
```

Comment: Very similar to your previous question: [mysqli error: [1093: …](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148819/mysqli-error-1093) and please see this for how to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I still don't understand how it works.. Sorry

Comment: Read that answer again. And try to rewrite the correlated subqueries into JOIN syntax.

Comment: I tryed.. I always get an error message back. Thank you anyway

Comment: Let's see your attempt at `JOIN`, plus the entire error message.